# flash object not displaying in firefox

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, flash, vimeo

When i first load the page the flash container div is set to display:none, i then apply some jQuery to .fadeIn() and set the div heigth and width size. Fine. But within this div i embed the flash object this way:

```
<object width="692" height="389">
    <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent"> 
    <param name="movie" value="http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=<?php the_field('vimeo'); ?>&amp;server=vimeo.com&amp;show_title=0&amp;show_byline=0&amp;show_portrait=0&amp;color=ffffff&amp;fullscreen=1&amp;autoplay=0&amp;loop=0" />
    <embed src="http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=<?php the_field('vimeo'); ?>&amp;server=vimeo.com&amp;show_title=0&amp;show_byline=0&amp;show_portrait=0&amp;color=ffffff&amp;fullscreen=1&amp;autoplay=0&amp;loop=0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" width="692" height="389">
    </embed>
</object>
```

Where:

```
<?php the_field('vimeo'); ?>
```

is a generated Id via php.

Basically the issue is that I need to use the old flash object only for firefox as otherwise by using the iframe method form vimeo I'd get random black screen for the video, the solution is to use the flash object, only for firefox but for some reasons I don't get the video displayed while i can see the object in the DOM.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I think it's because jQuery is not equipped to manipulate opacity of a third-party multimedia object, even though it is embedded into standard HTML markup.

Your best bet could be just positioning an invisible DIV with the same dimensions on top of it and then just fading that in/out (but this is just pure speculation)."

from:

[Why does JQuery not fade a flash object properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229166/why-does-jquery-not-fade-a-flash-object-properly)